# How to add onChange function for all HTML

Tags: onchange

my code
html += '<select onchange="status_update(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,' + data[count].petition_list_id + ')"">สถานะอนุมัติไม่อนุมัติ';

not working

Comment: use eventListener

Comment: you could search javascript about that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.